# Robot Framework + Appium + Perfecto

Tags: appium, robotframework, perfecto

I'm trying to integrate Perfecto Mobile with Robot Framework, unfortunately i haven't been successful. Does anyone have experience with this? Thanks!

Comment: Better description would be necessary to even try to help you.

Comment: not clear ! please give more description

Answer (score -1):

Perfecto does't support Robot FW out of the box. 
It really depends what you are trying to do but there are 2 options for you:
- Perfecto has open API - You can implement your keywords using the API.
- DevTunnel - There is a new capability that allows you to work with device directly (adb) behaving as it is connected to your workstation - This approach has prons and cons - You will not have to make any implementation from one hand however it will not be the right solution for CI automation.

Comment: I see this https://help.perfecto.io/perfecto-help/content/perfecto/integrations/robot_framework.htm